# Spring Boot Controller Jasper Report Blank PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

```
@GetMapping(value = "/report/pdf/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadInvoice(@PathVariable Long id,Model model) throws JRException, IOException  {

        String reporPath="src/main/resources/templates/pages/user";
        
        
        JasperReport compileReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(new FileInputStream(reporPath + "/test.jrxml"));    
        
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compileReport,parameters);
        
        byte data[] = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=invoice.pdf");


        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF).body(data);
        
        
    }
```

---

Please help me to solve this problem I can't to solve this problem is still blank Jasper

Answer (score -1):

See same as method miss parameter 3rd is data input

**fillReport(compileReport,parameters)**

Updated same:

**fillReport(compileReport,parameters, dataInput)**